# How can I set Dark Theme in WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-dark-theme

I want to display the content of web pages inside my webview with dark theme. For Example:- When youtube.com is visited then youtube's content should be loaded with dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

if you are targeting certain sites you can insert java script code into the url when load the url and then change the body color incase of youtube you might need to trigger click on a certain button so that it will change it to youtube default dark but.

you can also retrieve the data from youtube and build your own design for it but it will be it wont help you if you want it to couple of sites.

for exmaple building your own youtube app with cool colors and dark mode design

if you find any other sulution to that problem i will be glad to hear

Comment: But is it legal to modify youtube site to such extend?

Comment: I think that injecting java script to youtube to change colors is legal , but I dont know if building your own youtube app is legal. but there are applications in the playstore who build there own youtube apps for example there is an app that allows you to watch youtube vidows while doing other things (you can see small videos in  the side of the phone)